# proguard: can't find referenced field 'java.lang.Boolean default'

Tags: reference, field, proguard

```
interface Foo {

    Boolean getDefault();
}


class FooImpl implements Foo {

   private Boolean defaultValue;

   @Override
   public Boolean getDefault() {
      return defaultValue;
   }
}
```

Proguard: can't find referenced field 'java.lang.Boolean default' in class FooImpl. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use proguard property file like this

```
-injars in_name_of_ajr.jar
-outjars out_jar.jar
-printmapping mappingfile_name.map
**-libraryjars  <java.home>/lib/rt.jar**  // this is solution for ur question 
-libraryjars  .. any other jar location if you user them as libs in your project

-target 1.7 // java version
-keep public class your_package_name.MainClass { 
      public static void main(java.lang.String[]); 
}
```